# Tensorflow save weights InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, save

Using the following minimal piece of code

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model.save_weights('my_checkpoint')
```

I obtain the following error (the last part I translated as it was printed in my native language)

```
InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__SaveV2_dtypes_5_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Failed to
create a NewWriteableFile: my_checkpoint_temp/part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate15549814337234001039 : The syntax 
of the file name, folder name or volume name is incorrect.
; no protocol option [Op:SaveV2]
```

How is this possbile? I am using tensorflow 2.14.0

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node
> _*wrapped__SaveV2_dtypes_5_device*/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Failed to create a NewWriteableFile:
> my_checkpoint_temp/part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate15549814337234001039
> : The syntax  of the file name, folder name or volume name is
> incorrect. ; no protocol option [Op:SaveV2]

The problem appears to be associated with the file path or name when attempting to store the model weights. The error message specifically highlights an issue with the filename "my_checkpoint_temp/part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate15549814337234001039.

Make sure you provide a valid file path for saving the weights

Example:-

> model.save_weights('/path/to/your/directory/my_checkpoint')